Schefflera help
My schefflera that I have had for 18+ years just started to have some issues. From the bottom the leaves are turning brown and stalks are falling off. I am seeing tan spots on the leaves. It has moved to my mom’s so I didn’t know if humidity could be a factor. What are your ideas?

pictures please
